# Expand TextField height based on content upto certain lines

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm trying to make a `TextField multi-lined` only when the content is more than one line. Similar to WhatsApp chat TextField which is expanded to a maximum of 6 lines only when the content is ateast 6 lines.

I've tried **`maxLines`** property of `TextField`, but it makes it 6 lines of height whether or not there is any content in it.

I've also tried setting **`keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline`**, but it doesn't change the height of the TextField.

Please help me to resolve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
new TextField(
    maxLines: null,
    keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
)
```

Comment: That's very nice. But can i make it maximum of 6 lines

Comment: Can i set maxHeight for the TextField using any other widget or something like that?

Comment: have you tried new TextField(
  keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
  maxLines: 6,
)

Comment: Yeah i tried that. It makes the TextField 6 lines even if there is no text.

Comment: I've also tried setting maxHeight by wrapping it inside a Constrained box but it overflows extra one line below the box

Comment: I have no idea about the same. It's documented (but not entirely clearly) https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/TextField/maxLines.html